# Flutter Hot Reload não ativando - Waiting for observatory port to be available

Tags: android, flutter

Ao rodar qualquer aplicação em flutter (no terminal, android studio ou visual code) no meu dispositivo Android LG K11 Android Nougat, o processo do flutter não passa desta linha:

```
Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

Quando eu rodo em outro dispositivo Android a aplicação funciona tranquilamente e ativa o hot reload.

Vou deixar o log do flutter run -v abaixo:

````
C:\Users\junio\Development\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter
-Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages
                A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0c001b
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" (Raw: "com.facebook.FacebookActivity")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x5b0
              E: activity (line=65)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" (Raw: "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                E: intent-filter (line=68)
                  E: action (line=69)
                    A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.VIEW" (Raw: "android.intent.action.VIEW")
                  E: category (line=71)
                    A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                  E: category (line=72)
                    A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" (Raw: "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")
                  E: data (line=74)
                    A: android:scheme(0x01010027)=@0x7f0c0046
              E: provider (line=78)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" (Raw: "androidx.core.content.FileProvider")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.fileprovider" (Raw:
                "br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.fileprovider")
                A: android:grantUriPermissions(0x0101001b)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                E: meta-data (line=83)
                  A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" (Raw: "android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS")
                  A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0f0000
              E: activity (line=88)
                A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030007
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity" (Raw:
                "io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
              E: activity (line=92)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" (Raw: "com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity")
              E: activity (line=93)
                A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" (Raw:
                "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
              E: service (line=102)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" (Raw:
                "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService")
                A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" (Raw:      
                "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
              E: activity (line=107)
                A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw:
                "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
              E: meta-data (line=112)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f080004
              E: provider (line=124)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" (Raw:
                "com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.FacebookInitProvider" (Raw:
                "br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.FacebookInitProvider")
              E: receiver (line=129)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver" (Raw:
                "com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver")
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                E: intent-filter (line=132)
                  E: action (line=133)
                    A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED" (Raw:
                    "com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED")
              E: receiver (line=136)
                A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.facebook.CampaignTrackingReceiver" (Raw: "com.facebook.CampaignTrackingReceiver")       
                A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" (Raw: "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES")     
                A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                E: intent-filter (line=140)
                  E: action (line=141)
                    A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" (Raw: "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")     
[  +86 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on LM X410 F.
[   +7 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS shell am force-stop
br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug
[+2573 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS shell pm list packages
br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug
[+1508 ms] package:br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS shell cat
/data/local/tmp/sky.br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.sha1
[  +91 ms] 70c800778bbad195d06bce67fbf266093e201f82
[   +1 ms] Installing APK.
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +49 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
        Version 30.0.1-6435776
        Installed as C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +50 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS install -t -r
C:\Users\junio\Projects\space\constante\constante-mobile\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
[+10261 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                  Success
[   +3 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... (completed in 10,3s)
[  +12 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS shell echo -n
460f0ecff4b4eddb66f73596bf8cb3af7287ecb6 > /data/local/tmp/sky.br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug.sha1
[ +138 ms] LM X410 F startApp
[   +7 ms] executing: C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s LMX410CE596SPNSOWS shell am start -a
android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode    
true --ez verify-entry-points true br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug/br.com.spacerocket.constante.MainActivity
[+1571 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000
cmp=br.com.spacerocket.constante.debug/br.com.spacerocket.constante.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +3 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...```
````

Comment: O mesmo acontece com qualquer projeto, inclusive novos ou só com esse em particular?

Comment: Com qualquer projeto

Comment: Pesquisando pelo problema rapidamente vi algumas pessoas comentando sobre nomeação de arquivos incorreta... tentou algo relacionado ao que essa issue cita? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51269

Comment: Já sim, mas não eu não alterei nada de nome não, acredito que esse fosse o caso não funcionaria em outros celulares ou emulador. O problema está sendo especificamente com este modelo de celular que é o meu.

Comment: Acredito que [esse](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25455#issuecomment-448671172) possa ser o seu problema. Envolve dar uma olhada nas configurações de desenvolvedor do Android. Como eu não tenho esse modelo, não posso confirmar hehe.

Comment: Opa, infelizmente eu já tentei procurar essa opção no meu modelo mas não achei de jeito algum :/ (Se é que existe nesse modelo). Me parece ser especifico Meizu M6 Note, Android 7.1.2, Flyme 7.0.1.0G